# Microsoft C++ compiler is too annoying! Is there an alternative for compiling for Windows 32/64bit?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, compiler-construction

I am so frustrated with the Microsoft C++ compiler (not Visual). I am really annoyed at how it uses

```
int _tmain(
```

and

```
_TCHAR* argv[]
```

as well as many other things. I just want to use straight C++ like you would in GCC. Is there an alternative?

**Thanks to all the responses**. I was really just looking for a way of not using *Microsoft Style* code. This is what helped me -

1. Remove `#include "stdafx.h"`
2. Rename main method to -

`int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
return 0;
}`

**And it works!**

Comment: The `as well as many other things` comment was little misleading giving the impression that You wanted to change the compiler for more reasons than just getting rid of Microsoft specific implementations. Anyways, glad you found a solution.

Comment: Refer this for understanding T-Stuff: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use `_tmain()` and `TCHAR` if you do not want to. Just create an empty project, add an empty source file to it and start writing

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
}
```

On VC++ 2010 Express you can just compile and execute it straight away. I don't remember if previous versions require that you set the project type.

Answer (score 4):

You can try **[MinGW-32/64](http://www.mingw.org/)** for windows.

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? My comment on question already states why I suggest another compiler and not the modifications suggested by others. Phew..

Answer (score 4):

The `_tmain`/`_TCHAR` stuff is optional (you can read more about this on MSDN, [Generic-Text Mappings in Tchar.h](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c426s321%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)).  You can delete the `tchar.h` file and `#include` from your project and directly use `wmain`/`wchar_t` (or `main`/`char` for ANSI) if you so choose.

Comment: Thanks, instead of choosing a different compiler, you allowed me to get past this with a simple tweak. I just removed the #include "stdafx.h" and renamed my main method to int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{} and it worked! :P

Answer (score 0):

You can get gcc for Windows. Look at the [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com) site. I know MS lets you use _tmain, TCHAR etc, but its the first I've heard that it actually requires you do to so, are you sure you're not missing some option somehere?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [gcw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gcw/) and [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) but I have had varying results with both so YMMV...